# Wordpress Action Hook inside Classes

Tags: plugins, hooks, actions, oop

The WordPress plugin is functioning correctly, and within the functions.php file, I aim to establish tabs using arguments and hooks. These tabs should consist of both a tab menu and tab content. However, after initiating the arguments, the classes should include add_action for the menu and add_action for the content. I believe I have followed the proper procedures, but I am not receiving any values in the do_action function. Could you please advise on where I might be encountering issues within the code?

```
function tabRun() {
    global $tabs;
    
    $tabs = array(
        array(
            'tab_name' => 'menu1',
            'tab_content' => 'content1'
        ),
        array(
            'tab_name' => 'menu2',
            'tab_content' => 'content2'
        ),
        // Dodajte više tabova po potrebi
    );
}

add_action('create_tab', 'tabRun');

class MyTabs {
    public function add_tabs() {
        global $tabs;

        foreach ($tabs as $tab) {
            add_action('mytabs_menu', function () use ($tab) {
                echo '<div id="tab-menu-' . esc_html($tab['tab_name']) . '" class="tab-menu" >' . esc_html($tab['tab_name']) . '</div>';
            });

            add_action('mytabs_content', function () use ($tab) {
                echo '<div id="tab-content-' . esc_html($tab['tab_name']) . '" class="tab-content">' . esc_html($tab['tab_content']) . '</div>';
            });
        }
    }
}

if (class_exists('MyTabs')) {
    global $my_tabs;
    $my_tabs = new MyTabs();
    $my_tabs->add_tabs(); // Dodajte ovu liniju da biste aktivirali dodavanje tabova
}

do_action('create_tab'); // Dodajte ovu liniju za poziv funkcije tabRun()
do_action('mytabs_menu'); // Dodajte ovu liniju za prikaz tabova u WordPress temi
do_action('mytabs_content'); // Dodajte ovu liniju za prikaz tabova u WordPress temi
```

Comment: `add_tabs()` only runs on the `create_tab` hook. When does that run? Your `do_action()` calls are only going to produce output if the `create_tab` is run.

Comment: adding an action isn't like setting up a state tree that WP figures out once you're done, they're time sensitive events. It would be easier and more accurate to plot them out on a timeline. E.g. you can't use `add_action( 'init'` inside a theme template because that action has already happened in the past and would require time travel to work. Think of `add_action` as "From this point onwards, when the event action named "action name" happens, run this callback function"

Comment: also there is no `do_action( 'create_tab' )`

Comment: I tried to make a change, edit, if there is some logic, but I always have a problem when the arg needs to be transferred to the hook, I want to be able to start the hook from one function, but then start two hooks from classes mytabs_menu, mytabs_content, which will contain arg...

Comment: your new code changes things greatly, and also has a new problem, you added a new `tabRun` function that sets the tabs, but you call `do_action('create_tab');` _after_ `add_tabs` is called, not before, so how would `add_tabs` know about them? The tabs have not been set yet! It would need to know how to look into the future as `$tabs` has not been given a value yet. **The order the code runs in matters.** Remember, code is executed from the top downwards, but `add_action` does not run the function, it tells WP when to run the functions (aka when `do_action` is called )

Comment: As an aside, the use of hooks here is very overcomplicated, is there a reason not to use a member variable on the class, and have a function to add a tab e.g. `$my_tabs->add_tab( 'tabname', 'tabcontents' );`? And why use a global variable when you could use `$this->tabs`?

Comment: It seems complicated, I wanted to avoid using $this->tabs, but it will eventually end up there. I thought one action could trigger all other actions.